# What's the title of this anime about a girl and her servant in a hotel?

Tags: inu-x-boku-ss

I do remember what it is about but forgot the name of it. Here's some info about it: there is a girl that moves into a hotel. Then the servant for her is a guy and the guy has been waiting for her his whole life. It turns out this hotel is a supernatural hotel and the guy has a superpower of a dog or something like that. When the girl was little her mum and dad always spent time with her sister so she was jealous. Then I think her dad finds her a husband when she was little. She starts to write him letters. He stops and makes his servant (the guy from the start) to write her letters back and pretend that it is him. The servant starts to fall in love with her. Then he stays at the hotel and is her servant. Then the future husband comes to the hotel and stays for a bit, spending time with her. However, she hates him because he stopped writing letters back to her.

That's all I know about it. Please if you get what I've written and know what it's called please let me know. It would help a lot.

Comment: This one ?? http://myanimelist.net/anime/11013/Inu_x_Boku_SS

Comment: If you have the answer please post it as an answer instead of just as a comment.

Comment: Yes I am, I was posted it as comment coz I didn't sure about it. Now I am

Answer (score 5):

Judging on your preferences, it might be ["Inu x Boku"](http://myanimelist.net/anime/11013/Inu_x_Boku_SS) which is aired in Winter 2012.